# Filter Lat Long values based on conditions and taking average

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

My list contain a huge data of lat lon values, and I am dealing with  data in a farm. So I may need accuracy upto 1 meter so i decided
to filter data upto 6 decimal places.

I need to take average lat lon values of records which has same lat lon value up to 6 digits.

```
Sample data : 

148.0155503
148.0155504
148.0155506
148.0155507
148.0155508
148.015551
148.0155511
148.0155513
148.0155514
148.0155515
148.0155517
148.0155518
148.0155519
148.0155521
148.0155522
148.0155524
148.0155525
148.0155526
148.0155528
```

So output will be like average of below values as first object in the list

```
148.0155503
148.0155504
148.0155506
148.0155507
148.0155508
```

Then second as like average of below values so on..

```
148.015551
148.0155511
148.0155513
148.0155514
148.0155515
148.0155517
148.0155518
148.0155519
```

So the final output will look like

```
148.0155505
148.0155514
.
.
.
```

Note : here i am taking only lon values, the same condition should be applied to lat also .

I have tried the below method but it doesnt work

```
var filteredList = soilData
                 .Skip(1)
                  .Aggregate(
                 soilData.Take(1).ToList(),
                 (a, x) =>
                 {
                     if (Math.Abs(x.Latitude-a.Last().Latitude) >= Convert.ToDecimal(.000001))
                     {
                         a.Add(x);
                     }
                     return a;
                 });
```

This method return some wrong data , also no idea how to take the average in this.
Can someone help me to resolve this ?

Comment: Shouldn't `148.0155506` become `148.015551` (i.e. midpoint rounding)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It will not be , 148.0155506 will not be treated as 148.105551

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ to do this:

```
var data = new List<double>
    {
        148.0155503,
        148.0155504,
        148.0155506,
        148.0155507,
        148.0155508,
        148.015551,
        148.0155511,
        148.0155513,
        148.0155514,
        148.0155515,
        148.0155517,
        148.0155518,
        148.0155519,
        148.0155521,
        148.0155522,
        148.0155524,
        148.0155525,
        148.0155526,
        148.0155528
    };

var filteredList = 
    (from item in data
     group item by Math.Floor(item * 1000000) / 1000000
     into gr
     select new {gr.Key, Average = gr.Average()}).ToList();
```

You'll end up with this:

```
[
    {
        "Key": 148.01555,
        "Average": 148.01555056
    },
    {
        "Key": 148.015551,
        "Average": 148.01555146249999
    },
    {
        "Key": 148.015552,
        "Average": 148.01555243333334
    }
]
```

If you'd rather end up with a list of just the averages change the last line to:

```
select gr.Average()).ToList();
```

And you'll get:

```
[
    148.01555056,
    148.01555146249999,
    148.01555243333334
]
```

Comment: I am getting error on gr.Average() IGrouping<decimal,data> does not contain definition of Average

Comment: Are you absolutely certain it says `IGrouping<decimal, data>`? I think you have a typo somewhere.